command not found: solana-test-validator
After I installed solana-cli version 1.18.1, I tried to run the validator locally in the root directory but the command is not found. Did I miss something? My machine is a Mac M1.
(base) MacBook-Pro-126 ~ % solana --version      
solana-cli 1.18.1 (src:5d824a36; feat:756280933, client:SolanaLabs)
(base) MacBook-Pro-126 ~ % anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.29.0
(base) MacBook-Pro-126 ~ % solana config get
Config File: /Users/y/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899 
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/y/.config/solana/id.json 
Commitment: confirmed 
(base) MacBook-Pro-126 ~ % solana-test-validator
zsh: command not found: solana-test-validator


solana-test-validator command worked fine before, but suddenly it doesn't work!

Did you resolve it ? It works in my Vs code but not on mac Terminal

Did you install the Solana CLI using Homebrew? In that case, the test validator is not included.
Please install it manually, following these instructions:
https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/install#macos--linux
Make sure it's in your PATH. The install script will notify you if a change is necessary.
The CLI has a solana-install command for updating or managing multiple versions, so it's a better choice than Homebrew.

I installed it manually and not using Homebrew,and I reused solana-install init 1.18.1 and the command still doesn't work

OK that's weird. But just running solana works? Did you check the folder with the binaries (which solana to find it)?

Yes, solana is working fine, and I can find its binaries using which solana

Haven't faced this,
Try reinstalling/updating your CLI suite to 1.18.8 (recommended for anchor 0.30.0)
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"

Installation guide https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/setup-local-development#for-linux-macos-wsl-or-other-unix-like-systems

I installed it exactly according to this guide, but suddenly this command doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it anymore

if it's crucial to use solana-test-validator, could you check out bankrun https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/

This seems to be only available for the JS client, do you know if it's possible to run test-validator by building a docker on MacOS?

Haven't had the need to do this but check this out https://gist.github.com/beeman/6e52d53ddb45a353d0efe181d9c6e103
It downloads the CLI suite and should contains the test-validator in it.
